# Click element(selector by child text)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

i need click checkbox on page with table:

```
<table>
   ....sample item...
    <tr>                 
    <td align="middle"><input type="checkbox" class="enableMacacl" checked=""></td>
    <td>04:18:D6:3E:B4:79</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

but i need click this checkbox with selector by text "04:18:D6:3E:B4:79". How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it inside `<label for="checkboxId"></label>` and then give `id="checkboxId"` to checkbox.

```
<table>
   ....sample item...
    <tr>                 
    <td align="middle"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="enableMacacl" checked=""></td>
    <td><label for="checkbox">04:18:D6:3E:B4:79</label></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i cant did it, because this page not my, i tried emulate click on web page, but i cant change html code page